# Dynamics CRM sdk - Connecting with Helper code

Tags: c#, .net, crud, helper, dynamics-crm-online

I got a little problem:
I want to use the Microsoft CRM sdk helper code to connect to my online crm and retrieve data to my c# console application. But I am always getting the same exception:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: "https://organisation.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=80"
```

I basically want to program this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx

If I run the sample code "QuickStart" which is also using the helpercode i get the same exception.

QuickStart Sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334689.aspx

I am using the .NET Framework 4.5.2 and I have set up my console application like the example in the msdn documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481588.aspx

Can anyone help me to fix this error,
or can anyone help me to connect to CRM to retrieve data like in this CRUD example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx)?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Its not your imagination - I should have been able to connect with those samples easily and I get the same Metadata error.   I am suspicious about the service discovery steps in those samples. disco.  and dev. (device)     I use OAuth and the newer REST endpoints so I don't actually use those samples concept in production.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Glad to be not alone with this error. Maybe I should also go with OAuth & the REST Endpoints.

Comment: Do a Full Path realistic example with the REST endpoints with the actual tools and production processes you intend to use before you bet the farm on the REST methods.  You may be in for a rude surprise.   I am considering going back to the "old" service based concepts.  A simple GetVersionAPI and an account list from CRM can reveal a lot about how your environment can affect how the Rest stuff behaves in the real word in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem with recompiling the whole project with the .NET Framework 4.6.2.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051700